# How do I set root user's home directory?

Tags: linux, unix

Let's say I want to change root user's home directory. How would I do this? I tried:

```
# usermod -d /foobar root
usermod: user root is currently used by process 1
```

But I get this error. If you can't change the home when a process is running, it would seem immutable, since process 1 always runs. But surely that can't be right?

Comment: The usermod tool tries to prevent you shooting yourself in the foot, by preventing you changing the home directory of an account that's in use. There are other approaches, such as KamilCuk's answer, but based on the comments in the deleted answer, it sounds like you might be better explaining a bit of the why, whcih may give you an overall better answer.

Comment: Like Anya says this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: I want to do it because I want the app running in the container to not look for anything outside the app's install directory, and since the app is running as root, and the app install directory is not /root, I want ~root to be the directory I nominate.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set root user's home directory?

Edit /etc/passwd and reboot the system.

You can also just mv the /root dir and create a symlink from `/root` to that dir.

Comment: In this case I can't reboot the system because it's a container, and when it reboots it will be back to its original state.

Comment: So modify the image. I do not understand.

Comment: Well, the setup we have here is that we use a standard Amazon image and any modifications get done by a script as its starting up. That's not maybe what I would have chosen, but that's how we have it here.